# SQL / Django views conditional cumulative sum of values

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, django-views, window-functions

Pretty new to SQL and Django, I am trying to create a query to cumulate the value of column A (integer) if the value in column B (string) is different. This cumulation should be done based on date (column C).

Here is the data:

```
Column A Column B Column C 
2.0      Rock     2020-08-08
3.0      Paper    2020-09-08
25.0     Rock     2021-09-09
12.0     Rock     2021-10-10
5.0      Paper    2021-11-11
```

Based on this data, I would like to have a third column D, which will represent the cumulative value such as follow:

```
Column A    Column B Column C    Column D
2.0         Rock     2020-08-08  2.0
3.0         Paper    2020-09-08  5.0
25.0        Rock     2021-09-09  28.0
12.0        Rock     2021-10-10  15.0
5.0         Paper    2021-11-11  17.0
```

Comment: The column ColumnC contains duplicate days. This means that the order of the rows is not uniquely defined.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "If column B is different"...

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I mean that if in Column B you find a string that already existed previously, then only the value (Column A) of the latest string  (Column B) will be used in the cumulative sum. When we find the first Paper record, then the cumulated sum is Paper (3) and Rock (2) so a sum of 5. Next record, Rock's value change to 25, so the cumulative sum is 28 (25+3), and so on. Does it make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a query you can do it with a self join and `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, 
       t1.ColumnA + COALESCE(FIRST_VALUE(t2.ColumnA) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ColumnC ORDER BY t2.ColumnC DESC), 0) ColumnD
FROM tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.ColumnC < t1.ColumnC AND t2.ColumnB <> t1.ColumnB
ORDER BY t1.ColumnC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=af7b745f64ec68860703b2cd1095d304).

Comment: @forpass, if I were to have another column (with strings) in the original data, what should I modify for your query to work?

Comment: @MBtor `t1.*` returns all the columns of the table, so I believe that the code should work as it is, but I can't be sure without sample data and expected results.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however it does not work on my end. I would really appreciate if you could have a look at it. For this should I modify the data on this post or should I create another one so that your answer stays valid here?

Comment: @MBtor my code returns your expected results as you can see in the demo I provided, with the logic that you described in your question. If your requirement is different you should post a new question where you explain what you want with sample data and expected results.